# F# list of key value pairs to variable assignments

Tags: list, variables, f#

Given a list of key/value pairs:

```
do 
    [("A", 1);("B",2)]
    |> (fun list -> 
            for item in list do
                match item with
                | ("A", x) -> //expression assigning x to variable "A"
                | ("B", x) -> //expression assigning x to variable "B"
                | _ ->  //default expression
       )
```

Are there some expressions I can write that will accomplish the same thing as

```
let A = 1
let B = 2
```

I know in advance that the list has no more than 10 items, and that the items are tuples of <string, int> but don't know in advance whether "A" or "B" or other keys may be present or if the list is be empty.

Basically, decompose the list into a set of typed variables.

UPDATE: Notes on Context

In my app I receive a list of key/value pairs just like this from an upstream program maintained by a different team.  I expect certain keys to be in the list, which i want to assign to typed variables for later processing.  I'll throw an exception if ones I need are missing.  However I don't want to be locked in to any given set of variable names, except for the expected ones.  For all of them, I want to be able to assign them at run time.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What will you do with them afterwards?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do something with the variables later on in the code, then they will need to be in scope - so you will inevitably have to declare the variables in some way. The easiest option is to make them mutable and mutate them according to the values in the list:

```
let mutable A = 0
let mutable B = 0
```

To make the mutation a bit easier, you can create a lookup table with setters:

```
let setters = 
  dict [ ("A", fun x -> A <- x); ("B", fun x -> B <- x) ]
```

This now lets you iterate over the inputs, use dictionary lookup to get the appropriate setter and invoke it to set the variable value:

```
for var, value in [("A", 1);("B",2)] do
  setters.[var] value
```

With the limited context of your question, it is a bit hard to say whether this is a good way of achieving what actually motivated your question - as F# code, it does look like a bit ugly and it is likely that if you add more context, someone can suggest a better way.

Comment: Added some context to the original post

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some dynamic data that can be represented well as a map:

```
let data = Map [ ("A", 1); ("B", 2) ]

let a = Map.find "A" data
// throws an exception if "A" is not present

let b = Map.find "B" data
// throws an exception if "B" is not present

let c = Map.tryFind "C" data
// "C" is not present so c = None
```

Note: In F# the convention is for binding names (variable names) to start with a lower case letter.

Comment: nice!  that'll do fine!